# Selecting relative child tags jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am currently new to JavaScript (I am using jQuery) and I was wondering how I could select all the children `Something` tags from the following HTML

```
<Something attribute="first">
    <div class="container">
        <Something attribute="second" />
        <Something attribute="third">
            <Something attribute="fourth" />
        </Something>
    </div>
</Something>
<Something attribute="fifth">
    <Something attribute="sixth" />
</Something>
```

I had code like so to select both the child `Something` tags

```
$("Something[attribute='first']").children("Something").each({});
```

but this does not work because of the div in between.  How can I bypass all tags that are not `Something` and select only those elements that are one level deep if you remove all the tags that are not `Something`?  So if I want to query the children of the `Something` tag with attribute `first` I would get `second` and `third` (not `fourth` or `sixth`).  Similarly if I query `fifth` I would get `sixth`

**NOTE** Sorry for being unclear about this but I only want the `Something` tags one level after the `Something` tag whose children I am trying to find.  So for example in the above HTML I do not want the query to return the `Something` tag with attribute `fourth`.  **So in essence if you strip out the tags in between every other `Something` tag I want the tags that are only one level deep from the one in question**.

**NOTE** There can be other tags in between the `Something` tags, not just the one `div`.  For example the above can be

```
<Something attribute="first">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <Something attribute="second" />
            <Something attribute="third">
                <Something attribute="fourth" />
            </Something>
        </div>
    </div>
</Something>
<Something attribute="fifth">
    <div>
        <div>
            <Something attribute="sixth" />
        </div>
    </div>
</Something>
```

and the same selection criteria would apply.  So the results would be

```
first -> [second, third]
third -> [fourth]
[fifth] -> [sixth]
```

A recursive solution in pseudocode for what I want would be

```
function get_immediate_children_for(element, array_of_children) {
    $(element).children().each(function() {
        if (this.tagName == "SOMETHING") {
            array_of_children.push(this);
        }
        else {
            get_immediate_children_for(this, array_of_children);
        }
    });
}
```

and you would call this as so

```
var array_of_children = get_immediate_children_for($("Something[attribute='first']"));
```

Answer (score 3):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qdhnfdcx/

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("something");

function getChildren(name) {
    var list = []
  var len = name.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(name[i].parentElement.className != name[i].className) {
      for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        return list.push(name[i].children[j]));
      }
    }
  }
}

getChildren(elem);
```

Do the following:

```
var allChildren = document.getElementsByTagName("Something");
```

Then you can simply select the corresponding index:

```
allChildren[0];
allChildren[1];
```

Or you could loop and edit all of them:

```
for (var i = 0, len = allChildren.length; i < len; i++) {
  allChildren[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

If you want certain somethings not to appear then do:

```
for (var i = 0, len = allChildren.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(allChildren[i].getAttribute("attribute") != "fourth") {
    allChildren[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

If you only want the something tags one level after the something tags:

```
for (var i = 0, len = allChildren.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(allChildren[i].className == allChildren[i].parentElement.className) {
    allChildren[i].style.display = "none";.
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry!  I was unclear in my question.  I updated it with a note.  Sorry about that!

Comment: @Curious will this do? I think I might not quite understand but let me know it thats what you want

Comment: I guess my question was very unclear... I was looking for the `Something` tags that are only one level deep from the one in question if you remove everything else other than other `Something` tags

Comment: @Curious check now

Comment: Nope lol.  So if you go back to the example.  I was looking for a way to get all the children `Something` tags **that would be one level deep** if you removed all the tags from the document other than the `Something` ones

Comment: @Curious Oh I see. So You want all the something tags that are only 1 level deep relative to that one div right?

Comment: Yes! that is correct!  Sorry my html vocabulary might not have been good enough for this lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111325/discussion-between-asperger-and-curious).

Comment: @Curious oh! hang on.  I see the container div is also a something tag xD. Ok. So you want those right? The super something tags. The first level something tags relative to the entire document

Comment: yes!  `x` level relative to the document but only the children of the tag in question.  So if I had two outer level `Something` tags and I queried the first I would only get the children of the first

Comment: I will solve this, Im just trying to figure out the message haha. Let me do something

Comment: @Curious can you comment what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/c5wno3da/ so in the jsfiddle just comment out what you are targeting.

Comment: Thanks.  I upvoted every contribution you have made.  Also if you are trying to figure this out could you try and post a jquery solution?  Its not that important if you cannot though

Comment: Querying `first` from that link would get you `second`, `third` and `fourth`. Querying `fifth` would get you `sixth`, querying `third` would get you `seventh`

Comment: Hello, looking at your jquery code, I actually posted a solution. Ill post a nice jsfiddle.

Comment: Where did you post the solution exactly?

Comment: @Curious do you need the attributes? Ill post a jsfiddle

Comment: Yes the attributes would be great!

Comment: @Curious check out the jsfiddle. Now its easy to make a function out of it and you have so little code. No need for horrible Jquery xD

Comment: Anyways, my debugger and console is broken so I cant test those out until I restart my PC lol.Good Luck :D

Comment: @Curious what does the console say?

Comment: Could you take a look at the pseudocode I posted above for what I want?  That might help make this question more explicit

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT (due to edited question)**

If you want a single level after the child of a specific element, then use something like this:

```
$("Something[attribute='first']").children("div").children("Something").each({});
```

---

Instead of [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

(from jquery docs)

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Comment: I'm sorry! I was unclear in my question.  I updated it with a note

Comment: I updated the question again! I do not think I was clear at all in the beginning :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var smth = document.getElementsByTagName('Something')[0];
var chindren = smth.getElementsByTagName('Something');
for(var i = 0, el;el = children[i];++i){
//do what you want
}
```

**Edit 1 (final)**
I answered to the first edition of the question.
Possible answer is to convert / read current document as XML and manage accordingly. Or parse inner/outerHTML to a node tree. There are a lot of pitfalls on both ways (including browser comatibility, at least) but it is the only approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("Something").each(function() {
var childSomething = $(this).find("Something");
$.each(childSomething,function() {
//do something
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery find function to achieve that. Like this:

```
$("Something[attribute='first']").find("div > Something").each({});
```

Comment: That will give me everything that is more than one level deep.  I only want things that are one level deep if you strip out everything other than the `Something` tags.  What you said would return `fourth` also from my question.  But I do not want that

Comment: Updated selector in my answer to select immediate child of div.

Comment: I updated my question with another note to be more explicit.  Do you know how to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!  I do not believe that jQuery or Javascript either have a native way to do this but a simple recursive solution to this would be

```
function get_immediate_children_for(element) {
    var array_of_children = [];
    get_immediate_children_for_helper(element, array_of_children);
    console.log(array_of_children);
    return array_of_children;
}
function get_immediate_children_for_helper(element, array_of_children) {
    $(element).children().each(function() {
        console.log(this.tagName);
        if (this.tagName == "ACTIVITY") {
            array_of_children.push(this);
            console.log(array_of_children);
        }
        else {
            get_immediate_children_for_helper(this, array_of_children);
        }
    });
}
```

So that now `get_immediate_children_for($("Activity[path='']"))` would return the elements one level deep ignoring all other tags